# Dockerhub Automated Builds tagging

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I have created an automated build on dockerhub, but unfortunately I didn't find any proper documentation for those.

Basically, I am creating a system where docker automated build is triggered as soon as there is a commit in github repository. So how can I keep my docker tag a variable? Such that whenever there is a commit, the image being built is tagged with the latest commit's sha1.

I can put a regex in `branch name` or `tag name`, can't I put a regex in docker tag name? Here I wish to trigger the build by specifying the curl by docker tag name.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you want is possible. The only variable you can use in the docker tag name is `{sourceref}`, which expands to the branch or tag name.

I presume this was deliberate -- you'd vastly increase the number of images that Docker Hub had to store if each commit was given a different docker tag.

---

You could try using a continuous integration/deployment service to build the images outside of Docker Hub. There are many to chose from, but [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/) and [Circle](https://circleci.com/) are popular ones that should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Actually, I want to build an image per every commit in github repository, so I need to tag it with commit's sha1. In {sourceof} also, I don't think I can specify anything different apart from the `branch` or `tag` name?